# How do make an IF statement in Visual Studios 2010 C# from a combo box?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am having problems making an if statement in C# with Visual Studio 2010. I am a complete beginner and I need help.

I created a program which works out the perimeter and areas of different shapes, and I have created a combobox for the list of shapes like triangle, square, rectangle and paralellogram etc. I've created code for 3 of the shapes which you can see below, but I need a separate code for triangle, for area I want it to calculate the width and the length together and then divide by 2.

For perimeter I want it to multiply the width with 3 to work out the perimeter. I hope you understand what I mean folks.

```
    private void BtnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Here I am declaring my variables and I am converting my data types.

        double length = Convert.ToDouble(LengthArea.Text);
        double width = Convert.ToDouble(WidthArea.Text);

       //Here I am performing the caluclations for and the perimiter and area.
        double Area = length * width;
        double perimeter = 2 * (length + width);


        //Here I am outputting calculations to labels. 

        AreaAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(Area);
        AnswerPerimiter.Text = Convert.ToString(perimeter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the shape is important for you calculation, then you need to fetch this from your combobox. Afterwards, you should move the calculations of area and perimiter to separate methods.

It's not clear how you defined your shapes, but I made a small enum for this purpose.

```
public enum Shape {
    Square,
    Triangle,
    Parallelogram,
    OtherShapes
}
```

Then create a method for calculating the area of the shape, using the type of shape, the length and the width.

```
private double CalculateArea(Shape shape, double length, double width)
{
    switch (shape)
    {
        case Shape.Triangle:
            return (length * width) / 2;
            break;
        case Shape.Square:
        case Shape.Parallelogram:
            return length * width;
            break;
        case Shape.OtherShapes:
            //Calculate accordingly
            break;
    }
    return default(double);
}
```

Do the same for calculating the perimiter. Afterwards you can call these methods in the eventhandler for the button. Remember to fetch the shape from your combobox first.

```
private void BtnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here I am declaring my variables and I am converting my data types.

    double length = Convert.ToDouble(LengthArea.Text);
    double width = Convert.ToDouble(WidthArea.Text);

    Shape shape = Shape.Triangle; // This value should be fetched from your combobox

    //Here I am performing the caluclations for and the perimiter and area.
    double Area = CalculateArea(shape, length, width);
    double perimeter = CalculatePerimiter(shape, length, width);

    //Here I am outputting calculations to labels. 
    string AreaAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(Area);
    string AnswerPerimiter.Text = Convert.ToString(perimeter);
}
```